# Margin of error when considering a subset of the original data?

Tags: confidence-interval, error

I have a questionnaire that has collected around 1000 responses and is intended to model the general US population. My understanding is that 1000 responses is more than enough for a margin of error of 3% or so with a confidence level of 95%. OK, so far so good.

Let's say I find that the general population prefers vanilla to chocolate 60% to 40%.

Here's where I could use some help. If I subdivide that data set into say, women and men, now I have 250 women. Now I check to see how women feel, and it turns out when looking at just women, the numbers change to 55% vanilla and 45% chocolate.

Has my margin of error changed because now I'm looking at a smaller subset of just 250 people? Is it correct to report that 55% of women prefer vanilla with a 3% margin of error and confidence of 95%?

What if I do it again, so that the 120 Democratic leaning women (a subset of a subset) prefer chocolate 70% to 30%. Does my margin of error change yet again?

Any insight on this? Is this the "multiple comparison problem"?

Comment: Other things being equal estimates based on smaller samples are less precise.

Comment: With about 2500 subjects, pollsters often mention a 'margin of sampling error' of $\pm 2\%.$ Then follows detailed analysis of opinions of sub-populations (women, senior citizens, Catholics, etc.) without mentioning that for these smaller groups the margin of error is very much larger. Also, seldom mentioning that 'sampling error' assumes something like a simple random sample, when such unbiased samples are extremely difficult to achieve.